# How to configure .clang-format to skip formatting lines starting with certain strings like LOGGING_INFO in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-format

I don't want clang-format to format the code starts with LOGGING_INFO. My expect format is:

```
LOGGING_INFO(LOGGING_TYPE, "some strings" LOGGING_PRAMS(PARAM_TYPE0, variable0,
                                                        PARAM_TYPE1, variable1));
```

But if I enable the clang-format for this part. It will be formatted as:

```
LOGGING_INFO(LOGGING_TYPE, "some strings" LOGGING_PRAMS(PARAM_TYPE0, 
                                                        variable0,
                                                        PARAM_TYPE1,
                                                        variable1));
```

OR

```
LOGGING_INFO(LOGGING_TYPE, 
             "some strings" LOGGING_PRAMS(PARAM_TYPE0, variable0, PARAM_TYPE1, variable1));
```

I can use // clang-format to disable the format of the code, but so it is too much effort because it is used very frequently in my code.

What I expect is to find any method to tell the clang-format that when met the code starts with LOGGINF_INFO, the auto format will disable it.

For example, any regular expression written in the .clang-format to achieve the goals.

Comment: @Eljay That's way too much effort and it doesn't work for collaborators, as opposed to having a `.clang-format` file.

Comment: You can try putting `//` at the end of each of the lines where you want to force a line break.  You can use [configurator](https://clang-format-configurator.site/) to see how different clang-format setting affect the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak the following options:

[AlignArrayOfStructures](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignarrayofstructures)

[ColumnLimit](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#columnlimit)